# how to make space must be remains same after replacing text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have text, in which on selection I need to replace the text.

Here my requirement is, the space must be remain same after replacing the characters which contains spaces between them.

JavaScript:

```
    function getSel() {
    // obtain the object reference for the textarea>
    var txtarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
    // obtain the index of the first selected character
    var start = txtarea.selectionStart;
    // obtain the index of the last selected character
    var finish = txtarea.selectionEnd;
    //obtain all Text
    var allText = txtarea.value;

    // obtain the selected text
    var sel = Array(finish - start).join("*");
    //append te text;
    var newText = allText.substring(0, start) + sel + allText.substring(finish, allText.length);
    txtarea.value = newText;

    $('#newpost').offset({ top: 0, left: 0 }).hide();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var position;
    $('#newpost').hide();
    $('#mytextarea').on('select', function (e) {
        $('#newpost').offset(position).show();
        var txtarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
        var start = txtarea.selectionStart;
        var finish = txtarea.selectionEnd;
        $('#newpost p').text(Array(finish - start).join("*"));
    }).on('mousedown', function (e) {
        position = { top: e.pageY-5, left: e.pageX};
    });
    $('#newpost').hide();
});
```

Here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/J8vwEwM7jhOBS9q6tpdM?p=preview)

[image]

I am getting output as shown in above image but in expected output the space must not be replaced with asterisk .

Comment: It would help to show some sample expected input/output.

Comment: What’s your actual question or problem? Please provide an example with the current result and the expected result.

Comment: @Carcigenicat updated with expected output,please check once

Comment: Here is a JS-fiddle for anyone not liking Plunker (as me) https://jsfiddle.net/hbt6tn53/1/

Comment: @zeropublix not working

Comment: @anub ist not a answer. just a copy of your specific plunker

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.replace` instead, try this:

```js
console.log('g2ggg gggGG'.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '*'))
```

Your all string manipulation logic will be only 1 line:

```
newText = allText.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '*')
```

Comment: What if I enter a character outside the alphanumeric range? You should instead use `[^ ]` to match any character that isn't a space.

Comment: Yeah, but I did not try to cover every case, the original question was pretty simple.

Comment: And users are anything but simple. Your code doesn't even handle punctuation, for example.

Comment: Author probably would able to decide what criteria he need by himself, I gave him a point how to do it, and not to solve his business.

Comment: That sounds like hand-washing to me. When you answer on StackOverflow, you have a responsibility to help not just the OP, but also anyone and everyone in future who may have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good at regex so I used a for-loop but maybe this still helps you.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mytextarea').on('select', function (e) {
        var $output = $("#output");
        var $txtarea = $("#mytextarea");
        var start = $txtarea[0].selectionStart;
        var finish = $txtarea[0].selectionEnd;
        var subtext = $txtarea.text().substr(start, finish); 
        var out = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < subtext.length; i++) {
            var char = subtext[i];

            if (char == " ") {
                out += " ";
            } else {
                out += "*";
            }
        }

        $output.text(out);     
    });
});
```

Based on your code you can see the working example in **[this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hbt6tn53/13/)**:

Comment: Where do I even start on the inefficiencies? I mean building a new string (of arbitrary length) character-by-character, calling `.substr` to get a single character (use `subtext[i]` instead - strings are basically arrays of characters, after all), and so on...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thanks for the suggestions. I've edited my code